# hit java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after upgrade Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

Hit `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` after upgrade Android studio 3.0.

Already implemented Multidex, this issue only happened on Android 5.0 device.

Comment: please mention your code @ which line you get this error?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, including which class is not found, along with the LogCat or stack trace. It's not even clear if this problem is on the device or on the host!

Comment: Please provide some code or error log , so that we can give you a solution  for the same

Comment: Please add your logcat..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this issue few days ago. 
I had to disable instant run to fix this problem.
hopefully next update will resolve this issue.

Comment: This is weird , it work fine after i disable instant run , seem like android studio have some issue on that

Comment: Same here, I had some classes that are only used if a 3rd party library is available (as it is an optional feature). When instant Run is active, seems these classes are loaded no matter if they are needed or not, resulting in a NoClassDefFoundError.